# How to specify keyframes in a CSS animation positioned by a property value?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, keyframe

Keyframes in CSS animations are "positioned" in percentages:

```
@keyframes foo {
    0% { ... }
    50% { ... }
    100% { ... }
}
```

I have a simple animation where an object moves across the screen. However, the distance it moves is unknown.

Is it possible to make keyframes in a CSS animation, but their "position" in the animation is specified by a property value?

**Pseudo-code:**

```
@keyframes foo {
    0% {
        left: 0;
        background-color: green;
    }
    (left: 200px) { /* When the element's left position gets to 200px, this happens */
        background-color: red;
    }
    100% {
        left: 100%;
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible with CSS. The best you can do is pick a % close to where the element's left is 200px.

Comment: Keyframes are in percentages, if you are wanting to use css, you would have to have keyframes for different widths using media queries. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Impossible in CSS.

You can do this with [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), [MotionJS](http://mojs.io) or [VelocityjS](http://velocityjs.org) (faster)

Answer (score 0):

For these cases it is better to make animations using javascript and css to set the item using the prodiedad transition to be smooth movements